# C# Xamarin how to sum a column in SQLite with SELECT

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I'm writing a small program with Xamarin in C#, and I need to sum the values greater than 0 of one column of my table... At the moment I achieved this with:

```
var ent = conn.Table<Transaction>().Where(t => t.price > 0);
entLabel.Text = (ent.Sum(t => t.price)).ToString();
```

But I'd like to obtain the same result with a SELECT script. I tried this:

```
var ent = conn.Query<Transaction>("SELECT SUM(price) FROM Transaction WHERE price > 0");
entLabel.Text = ent.ToString();
```

Sadly, the result isn't a number, but a string like "System.Collection.something.blahblah".

Am I missing something? I searched the syntax (pasted below) in the docs and other sites and it seems the same as mine.

```
SELECT SUM(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: `conn.Query<Transaction>("SELECT SUM(price) FROM Transaction WHERE price > 0").FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var ent = conn.Query<Transaction>("SELECT SUM(price) FROM Transaction WHERE price > 0");
```

Use:

```
 var ent = conn.ExecuteScalar<int> ("SELECT SUM(price) FROM Transaction WHERE price > 0");
```

`ExecuteScalar` is used to return a scalar value from the database.